# What postscript object is 8-bytes normally, but 9-bytes packed?

Tags: memory-management, postscript

A packed array in Postscript is supposed to be a space-saving feature, where objects can be squeezed tightly in memory by omitting extraneous information. Like a null can be just a single byte because it carries no information. Booleans could be a signel byte, too. Integers could be 5 (or 3) bytes (if it's a small number). Reference objects would need the full 8-bytes that a normal object does. But the Postscript Manual says that packed objects occupy 1-9 bytes!

> When the PostScript language scanner encounters a procedure delimited by
>   { … }, it creates either an array or a packed array, according to the current packing
>   mode (see the description of the setpacking operator in Chapter 8). An
>   array value occupies 8 bytes per element. A packed array value occupies 1 to 9
>   bytes per element, depending on each element’s type and value; a typical average
>   is 2.5 bytes per element.  --PLRM 3ed, B.2. Virtual Memory Use, p. 742

So what object gets bigger when packed? And Why? Hydrogen-bonding??!

Answer (score 1):

Any value that you can't represent in 7 bytes or less, will need 9 bytes.

The packed format starts with a byte that contains how many data bytes follow, so any value that needs all 8 bytes of data will be 9 bytes including the leading length byte.

Comment: But isn't the length implicit in the type which is the first byte anyway. With your way an integer would have to be at least 6 bytes for length, type, 32bit-int. And nothing could be as short as 1.

Comment: Both the type and length fits in the first byte, the length only needs 3.2 bits. A value that needs zero bytes for the data fits in a single byte, like the integer value 0 or a null pointer.

Comment: Can I ask what your source for this is? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: @luserdroog: There is no other sourec needed. Unless the manual is lying, the quote in the question is all that's needed to determine that it simply has to be implemented that way.

Comment: the confusion lies in the first comment a year and a half ago.. the length is not implicit in the type, but depends on the actual value, ie. 9 bytes are requried for a signed  integer of actual value greater than 2^55.

Comment: @george: As the size can vary from 1 byte and up, the value has to be considered. There is no data type that you can store in zero bytes regardless of value.

Comment: @george and Guffa. I've realized that my dissatisfaction with the answer stems from unreasonable expectations on my part. I was hoping that an answer would specify a single postscript type, because I expected that detail to provide a key insight into how to implement the /packedarray type. The scope of my interest is limited to the Typical Implementation Limits from the PLRM 1ed, ie. Level-1 PostScript. So, integers and floats are 32 bits, no more. Composite sizes (and offsets in sub-arrays and sub-strings) are 16bits. Unpacked representation of all types fit in 8 bytes. I need to rework the Q